# Only show posts from current year based on meta_key - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have following `wp_query`. This query filters a custom post type based on a ACF(advanced custom field) date field. This query shows all the posts where the date provided in the custom field is equal to the current year or in the future.

```
<?php
  $current_year = date('Y');


  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'result',
    'meta_key'  => 'date_field',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key'        => 'date_field',
           'compare'    => '>=',
           'value'      => $current_year,
                                    )),
             );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
...
```

What i like to do is show the posts from the current year only. In the query above years in the future are still shown.

I tried removing the compare value or changing it to '==' . But then no posts are shown. I assume the reason is that the value inside the `'date_field'` is stored in format `('Ymd')`.

I looked at the [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/) and found a way to extract the year from the date field like so:

```
$date = get_field('date_field', false, false);
$date = new DateTime($date);
$date->format('Y');
```

But i'm not sure how i can implement that value inside my query. I tried changing the key value to `$date` but that doesn't show any posts.

Comment: Can you print the value of `get_field('date_field')` before creating a datetime? Also the operator should be `'='`.

Comment: yes i can print the value of the field, that part is no problem, i just don't know i can implement it into my query.

Comment: As in can you tell me what the value of the field is?

Comment: `string(10) "01/06/2016" `  This is the value inside the loop. Before the loop i can't get the value obviously

Answer (score 0):

ACF is saving the date as `‘YYYYMMDD’`

```
$args = [
    'post_type'    => 'result',
    'meta_key'     => 'date_field',
    'meta_value'   => date( "Ymd" ),
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```